# Wiki for emacs users

Tags: software-rec, emacs, wiki

I am looking for a new wiki software for a small private network. Since all users are very addicted to emacs, it would be nice to make everything "emacs compatible". What wiki software is most suitable for emacs users?

In particular it should be possible to navigate in the wiki inside of emacs (follow links etc.) and have a good mode which supports the wiki syntax perfectly.

It's also important to be able to save changes in emacs easily (perhaps even save changes before committing it to the wiki).

The wiki software should also meet other requirements, so it woul be nice if you could give multiple suggestions for a good emacs integration.

Comment: No idea if this fits your requirements, but apparently there is, *among others*, a `MediaWiki` mode (see [this `emacswiki.org` page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WikiModeDiscussion))...

Answer (score 2):

I propose a slightly different approach -- let the wiki's users use whatever editor they want by using *a [DVCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control)-backed wiki*, such as

- [`gitit`](http://gitit.johnmacfarlane.net/) can make use of git, darcs and mercurial; written in Haskell
- [`ikiwiki`](http://ikiwiki.info/) supports git, svn, bzr, monotone, mercurial, darcs, cvs and is written in Perl

Both *can* be used via a web browser as well, so making use of the underlying tools is no must.  They differ in features provided, so you'd better have a closer look on which one is the best fit for you.

Oh, and there are some [`wikifs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikifs)-clones using FUSE, e.g. [this `wikifuse` python script](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=NetworkFileSystems#wikifuse) (for MoinMoin only, I assume from the comments) or [`WikipediaFS`](http://wikipediafs.sourceforge.net/) (*unmaintained*, but accompanied by an [Emacs mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WikipediaFs)) for MediaWiki sites.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can do what you describe with Dokuwiki. It saves its pages in plain text files (structures in directories and subdirectories which are the same as the categories and subcategories that you create), which you can edit directly on the filesystem, outside of the web interface of the application. There is also `dokuwiki-el`, a [GNU Emacs frontend to the dokuwiki wiki engine](https://launchpad.net/dokuwiki-el).

Comment: How does editing dokuwiki pages directly on the filesystem work together with the revision control of dokuwiki pages?